# BigQuery Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm getting this error in BigQuery:
Error: syntax error at: 2:1 expecting: end of query but got: "CASE"

Query that I'm using is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

 CASE 
   WHEN
       t1.x<=t2.x 
   THEN 
       t1.x 
   ELSE
       t2.x 
 END id1, 

 CASE 
   WHEN
       t1.x<=t2.x 
   THEN 
       t2.x 
   ELSE 
       t1.x 
 END id2 

 FROM test1 t1 
 CROSS JOIN test1 t2 
 WHERE NOT t1.x = t2.x
```

Works in mysql but not in BigQuery.

Comment: if you change "END id1" to "END AS id1", does it change anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Bigquery supports `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Instead, use a subquery and `group by`:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN t1.x <= t2.x THEN t1.x ELSE t2.x END) as id1, 
             (CASE WHEN t1.x <= t2.x THEN t2.x ELSE t1.x END) as id2 
      FROM test1 t1 CROSS JOIN
           test1 t2 
      WHERE NOT t1.x = t2.x
     ) t
GROUP BY id1, id2;
```